# Ошибка при компиляции apk файла unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, apk

Когда я компилирую apk файл в unity, в конце он выдает мне ошибки:

> File C:\Users\Bekon.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
>
> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused,
> use --status for details
>
> > Configure project :launcher WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore. It will be removed in a
> > future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow
> > you to disable R8.
>
> FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
>
> ### 1: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':unityLibrary:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484.
> > Required by:
> > project :unityLibrary
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > Network is unreachable: connect
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > jcenter.bintray.com
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   ==============================================================================
>
> ### 2: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':launcher:mergeReleaseResources'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':launcher:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484.
> > Required by:
> > project :launcher
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > Network is unreachable: connect
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > jcenter.bintray.com
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   ==============================================================================
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 30s Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
>
> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
> F:\Unity\2020.3.12f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe
> -classpath "F:\Unity\2020.3.12f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar"
> org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8000m"
> "assembleRelease"
>
> stderr[
>
> FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
>
> ### 1: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':unityLibrary:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484.
> > Required by:
> > project :unityLibrary
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > Network is unreachable: connect
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > jcenter.bintray.com
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   ==============================================================================
>
> ### 2: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':launcher:mergeReleaseResources'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':launcher:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484.
> > Required by:
> > project :launcher
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > Network is unreachable: connect
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom'.
> > > jcenter.bintray.com
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   ==============================================================================
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 30s Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
> ] stdout[ Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be
> reused, use --status for details
>
> > Configure project :launcher WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore. It will be removed in a
> > future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow
> > you to disable R8.
>
> > Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> > Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> > Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> > Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> > Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> > Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease
> > Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> > Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> > Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> > Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> > Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> > Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> > Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> > Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> > Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> > Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources FAILED
> > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
> > Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> > Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest 17 actionable tasks: 17 executed ] exit code: 1
> > UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun
> > (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p,
> > UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit
> > waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at
> > <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
> > (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,
> > UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit
> > waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at
> > <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
> > (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir,
> > UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit
> > waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at
> > <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
> > UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args,
> > System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0) UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at
> > <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0) Rethrow as
> > GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
> > UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run
> > (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String
> > workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at
> > <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
> > UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute
> > (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at
> > <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
> > UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
> > (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at
> > <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0) Rethrow as BuildFailedException:
> > Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
> > UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild
> > (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at
> > <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
> > UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
> > (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at
> > <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
> > UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess
> > (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData,
> > System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String
> > installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName,
> > UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry
> > usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at
> > <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
> > UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
> > (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args,
> > UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at
> > <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
> > UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess
> > (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget
> > target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName,
> > System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height,
> > UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry
> > usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at
> > :0)
> > UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
>
> Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 125 seconds (124840 ms)
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
>
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors   at
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
> (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in
> :0    at
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean
> askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions)
> [0x00080] in :0
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Comment: Возможно, к ошибке не относится, но у меня часто были проблемы с компиляцией, если путь к проекту был на русском языке.

Comment: @Super3283u проверял, к сожалению не помогло

Comment: Попробуй проверить jdk, но я не уверен может кто по опытней подскажет

Comment: Согласен, что юнити очень часто **не** может скомпилировать проекты с русскими знаками в пути, а они у вас есть: `F:\Unity\проекты\norm...`. Также, возможно, во втором абзаце может быть что-то важное, хотя выглядит как просто предупреждение.

Comment: `Compressed texture user is used as icon. This might compromise visual quality of the final image. Uncompressed format might be considered as better import option.` вы не читали?

Comment: @МаксимФисман обновил текст ошибки и добавил детали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В тексте ошибки встречается :

> Network is unreachable: connect

при попытке скачать зависимость для вашего проекта. Либо на момент сборки у вас были проблемы с интернетом, либо проблема с доступом к ресурсам, откуда gradle пытается выкачать зависимость (aapt2 версии 3.6.0).

Проверьте доступность урл-ов: `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom` и `https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.0-6040484/aapt2-3.6.0-6040484.pom`. Сможете ли вы скачать эти пакеты просто вставив эти адреса в браузер? Если проблема именно в этом (может зависеть в том числе от того, где вы находитесь), попробуйте подключить какой-нибудь VPN, желательно с другой страны и попробовать собрать проект еще раз.

Кроме того, все-таки избавьтесь от кириллицы в пути к проекту, на это завязано множество проблем при сборке под android.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Попробовал скачать файл по первой ссылке, он скачался, а по второй же 403 forbidden

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ! VPN помог!!!